# Ubuntu 14 VM Stuck after boot with blinking underscore

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Ubuntu 14.04 - Stuck after boot. Screen shows blinking underscore. Even recovery leads to the same screen. Here is the screenshot. Even I cannot access the terminals.
[image]

What should I do to safely login?

Edit: There is some progress. Instead of underscore, now the boot process stuck saying systemd-journald: Got invalid event from epoll.
Any pointers here?

[image]

Comment: It's a VM. Boot from a backup.